# Intent and Bundle Relation

Tags: android, android-intent

While using Intent object we can put different types of data directly using its `putExtra()`. We can also put these extra data into a `Bundle` object and add it to `Intent`. So why do we need `Bundle` if we can do so using `Intent` directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes you need to pass only a `few variables` or `values` to some Other `Activity`, but what if you have a `bunch of variable's or values` that you need to pass to various `Activities`. In that case you can use `Bundle` and pass the `Bundle` to the required `Activity` with ease. Instead of passing single variable's every time.

Comment: `mExtras = new Bundle();` isn't this convincing enough? If not go check the `Intent.java`'s source code yourself.

Answer (score 18):

As you can see, the `Intent` internally stores it in a `Bundle`.

```
public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you need to pass a `Bundle` from one `Activity` to another. That's why `Intent` allows you to add `Bundle`s as extra fields.

**EDIT**: For example if you want to pass a row from a database along with some other data it's very convenient to put this row into a `Bundle` and add this `Bundle` to the `Intent` as a extra field.

Comment: i am asking why ? we are going to put same extra data in bundle and add that bundle into intent object.that we can put directly into the intent object.Is not it ?

Comment: Not, it isn't. You can just have a `Bundle` you need to pass. Do you really want to copy it field-by-field to the `Intent`. And if keys of the `Bundle` and the `Intent` will overlap? You can't know all the things people do so just remember that you're able to put a `Bundle` into an `Intent` and when you need it you'll know what to do.

Comment: A little example: you want to pass a row from a database along with some other data. It's very convenient to store this row in a `Bundle`. In one of my applications I use a list of `Bundle`s to pass several rows from a database.

Comment: It's not a convenient reason buddy.See the below reason that's better. +1 for that anyway.

Comment: It depends on how you estimate a level of convenience. I gave you an example from the real life but I haven't ever faced a situation when I had to put a lot of variables to the `Bundle` just because there's a lot of variables. Usually people create `Parcelable` objects in such situations. It's much safer and easier to understand and to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what @Lalit means is supposing your activity always passes the same variables to different intents, you can store all of them in a single `Bundle` in your class and simply use `intent.putExtras(mBundle)` whenever you need the same set of parameters.

That would make it easier to change the code if one of the parameters become obsolete in your code, for example. Like:

```
public class MyActivity {
    private Bundle mBundle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString("parameter1", value1);
        mBundle.putString("parameter2", value2);
    }
    private void openFirstActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(mBundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void openSecondActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(mBundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**OBS:** As stated already, `Intent` stores the parameters in a internal `Bundle`, and it's worth noting that when you call `putExtras`, the internal Intent bundle doesn't point to the same object, but creates a copy of all variables instead, using a simple `for` like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.mSize; i++) {
    put(array.keyAt(i), array.valueAt(i));
}
```