# pass string value from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, json, performance, parsing, android-intent

Hi I created android app ..It parse values using json.
I want to pass this value of json from one activity to another activity.
I have created the following code.

Activity1....

```
public class WaitressActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnDisplay;
    Button slide;
    SimpleSideDrawer slide_me;
    Button close;
    RelativeLayout window;
    ImageView clickWindow;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initActivity();

        clickWindow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent init = new Intent(WaitressActivity.this,
                        TaleActivity.class);
                init.putExtras("logo",s);
                startActivity(init);


            }
        });


}

public void jasonParser() {

        // Hashmap for ListView
        //ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JASONParser jParser = new JASONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);

            logo1=new String[contacts.length()];
            name1=new String[contacts.length()];
            distance1=new String[contacts.length()];
            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                logoCount=logoCount+1;
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);
                String lognitute = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                storeid = c.getString(TAG_STOREID);
                storename = c.getString(TAG_STORENAME);
                logo = c.getString(TAG_LOGO);
                String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                String num = c.getString(TAG_NUM);

                logo1[i]=logo;
                name1[i]=storename;
                distance1[i]=distance;

                // creating new HashMap
//               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
//              
//               // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
//               map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, latitude);
//               map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, lognitute);
//               map.put(TAG_STOREID, storeid);
//               map.put(TAG_STORENAME, storename);
//               map.put(TAG_LOGO, logo);
//               map.put(TAG_DISTANCE, distance);
//              //
//              // // adding HashList to ArrayList
//               contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<logoCount;i++){


        int distanceIntVlue = Integer.parseInt(distance1[i]);

        if (distanceIntVlue < 200 ) {

            distanceSecond.setText("Distance meter " + distanceIntVlue);
            nameSecond.setText(name1[0]);
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(logo1[0], clickWindow);
             s=logo1[0];

            if(i==1){
                int distanceIntVlue1 = Integer.parseInt(distance1[i]);
                distanceplace.setText("Distance meter " + distanceIntVlue1);
                name.setText(name1[1]);
                imageLoaderUp.DisplayImage(logo1[1], logoUp);
            }

            if(i==2){
                imageLoaderUp.DisplayImage(logo1[2], logoUnder);

            }
        }
        }




        //tale.showImage(logo);//       DownloadAndReadImage dImage = new DownloadAndReadImage();
//
//      clickWindow.setImageBitmap(dImage.readBitmapImage(logo));
        //
    }


public void initActivity() {
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndisplay);
        // Slider=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnslide);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclose);
        window = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);
        close.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        window.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        clickWindow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        distanceplace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place);
        nameSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.namesecond);
        distanceSecond = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.placesecond);
        logoUp=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        logoUnder=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    }
}
```

my second activity is,

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tale);
//
        Intent intent = getIntent();
       if (null != intent) {
                       urllogo= intent.getStringExtra("StringName");
        }
```

but the problem is, parameter "urllogo" always get the null value.
I searched and try many ways to do this. but in every time I got null value..
can any one help me thank you..pls...

Comment: Please add code of intent when you pass value StringName! And make sure you are not passing null data actually!

Comment: why dont you try to get the value which you are sending in your intent instead of "StringName" as suggested in the answers by @Eudhan

Comment: Make sure that the key values should match both while passing and retrieving from extras

Comment: possible duplicate of [pass value from one activity to another activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520299/pass-value-from-one-activity-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the keys used to put and get the strings from the Intent extras match:

```
init.putExtras("mystring",someString);
```

and

```
intent.getStringExtra("mystring");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code. See below line

```
urllogo= intent.getStringExtra("logo");
```

OR

Please check your value in variable "s", is it contain value or is it null already.

Answer (score 0):

You set "logo" as your reference:

```
init.putExtras("logo",s);
```

And you retrieved "StringName" instead of "logo":

```
urllogo= intent.getStringExtra("StringName");
```

Change as below in your second activity:

```
urllogo= intent.getStringExtra("logo");
```